# Jedis transaction.execGetResponse() giving null when inserting with hset

Tags: java, redis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, jedis

I am trying to insert hash map values to redis. When executing transaction using execGetResponse() getting below error. This method internally going through readByte() which results MINUS_BYTE leading to error.

```
    // Split fields between non updatable & updatable
    final Tuple2<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>> splitedFields =
            CacheTransformer.splitFields(storableProduct);
    final Map<String, String> invariantFields = splitedFields._1;
    final Map<String, String> updatableFields = splitedFields._2;

    // Create transaction & prepare operations
    final Transaction transaction = jedis.multi();

    // Use hsetnx on invariant fields (create if not exist, else do nothing)
    invariantFields.forEach((key, value) -> transaction.hsetnx(product.getFunctionalId(), key, value));

    // Use hget and hset on updatable fields (to do comparison between cached value and local value)
    updatableFields.forEach((key, value) -> {
        transaction.hget(product.getFunctionalId(), key);
        transaction.hset(product.getFunctionalId(), key, value);
    });

    // Commit transaction
    final List<Response<?>> execResponses = transaction.execGetResponse();

    // Close connection, we don't need it anymore from now on
    jedis.close();
```

"exception":{"cause":{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"processError","fileName":"Protocol.java","lineNumber":131,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Protocol","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"process","fileName":"Protocol.java","lineNumber":165,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Protocol","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"read","fileName":"Protocol.java","lineNumber":219,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Protocol","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"readProtocolWithCheckingBroken","fileName":"Connection.java","lineNumber":309,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getRawObjectMultiBulkReply","fileName":"Connection.java","lineNumber":276,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getObjectMultiBulkReply","fileName":"Connection.java","lineNumber":280,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execGetResponse","fileName":"Transaction.java","lineNumber":67,"className":"redis.clients.jedis.Transaction","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getProductFromRedis","fileName":"ProductRedisAdapter.java","lineNumber":276,"className":"com.renault.pan.ingestion.datamart.common.domain.client.ProductRedisAdapter","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"lambda$setAndGetProductFromCache$8621af43$1","fileName":"ProductRedisAdapter.java","lineNumber":230,"className":"com.renault.pan.ingestion.datamart.common.domain.client.ProductRedisAdapter","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"of","fileName":"Try.java","lineNumber":75,"className":"io.vavr.control.Try","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"setAndGetProductFromCache","fileName":"ProductRedisAdapter.java","lineNumber":230,"className":"com.renault.pan.ingestion.datamart.common.domain.client.ProductRedisAdapter","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"toCache","fileName":"CacheFn.java","lineNumber":50,"className":"com.renault.pan.ingestion.datamart.common.domain.dofn.CacheFn","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"lambda$toCacheFn$3be8e20$1","fileName":"CacheFn.java","lineNumber":44,"className":"com.renault.pan.ingestion.datamart.common.domain.dofn.CacheFn","nativeMethod":false},

Comment: Is this related to Apache Beam and Google Cloud Dataflow somehow ? (since you added those tags)

Comment: Yes, The project implemented using Apache Beam in GCP Dataflow

Comment: I found the issue, it is due to redis instance reach the memory limit. So, the job error out due to no further space to insert. Thank you..

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it? This improves the traceability of the post in order to help future members having the same issue.

Comment: Please check my comment, increased redis memory size to solve the issue.